# JNI create JVM by selecting which jvm.dll to load

Tags: visual-c++

I have several Java installations on my PC. Is it possible somehow to pass setting from which path jvm.dll should be loaded? Following code creates JVM using JNI:

```
void createJVM()
{

JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; 
JavaVMOption options[4]; 

int n = 0;     
char * str;
str= new char[1000];
sprintf(str, "-Djava.class.path=%S\\tst.jar", myPath);
options[n++].optionString = str; 

str= new char[1000];
sprintf(str, "-Djava.library.path=%S\\lib;%S", myPath, myPath);
options[n++].optionString = str;

str= new char[1000];
sprintf(str, "-Duser.dir=%S", myPath);
options[n++].optionString = str;

vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_4;
vm_args.nOptions = n;     
vm_args.options = options;     
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;


JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 options I am aware of: the first one is to set the PATH environment variable to jvm.dll directory you would like to use before running your executable and the second is to dynamic link to jvm.dll at run time, for example by using [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686944%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("D:\\desired_jvm\\jre6\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll"));
typedef jint (JNICALL *PtrCreateJavaVM)(JavaVM **, void **, void *);
PtrCreateJavaVM ptrCreateJavaVM = (PtrCreateJavaVM)GetProcAddress(hinstLib,"JNI_CreateJavaVM");
jint res = ptrCreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
//...
```